# Keeping Ruby C extension code DRY?

Tags: c, ruby, refactoring, stack, dry

I've written a simple [Stacks](https://github.com/rafalchmiel/structural/blob/master/ext/structural/stack.h) and [Queues](https://github.com/rafalchmiel/structural/blob/master/ext/structural/queue.h) [library](https://github.com/rafalchmiel/structural) in C as an extension for Ruby and came across needing to write the same two lines of code whenever I needed to retrieve an instance variable (in this case in `stack.h`):

```
VALUE stack;
stack = rb_iv_get(self, "@stack");
```

From what I found, this approach is quite slow compared to actual Ruby code (by as much as 0.1 second) and not at all DRY. Is there any way I can extract that out, to some kind of global variable or function? I tried putting these two lines outside any of the functions but I need access to self with `rb_iv_get(self, "@iv_name")` so that throws me an error.

Comment: Can't you pass `self` as an argument to the extracted function?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that works. It still is 0.1 seconds slower than a pure Ruby implementation (I'm comparing it to the `rdata` gem by the way). Any ideas on how to optimize it? Maybe the global variable approach would be quicker as it doesn't have to look up the instance variable each time?

Comment: In fact, I'm getting a segmentation fault error ([contents](https://gist.github.com/rafalchmiel/298d55ff2d663f402c66/raw/e89c17ee5f42d735c36749089234edf0849d37a8/gistfile1.txt)) when I try to use one of the Stack methods.

Comment: Well, the question is why you are writing it as a C extension in the first place. I guess you are expecting huge performance benefits in other places, so the 0.1 seconds may not make such a big difference in real usage. Besides, good benchmarks are really hard to do. How are you measuring the performance impact?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping to achieve (and this is my first C extension so it isn't a real project). I'm doing something along the lines of pushing 1 million times while checking top each time, and then popping half a million times and checking empty? each time. Not sure if this is a very good test to measure performance though... [These are example results](https://gist.github.com/rafalchmiel/2b7fc890037b0633bc6c/raw/bfd8508adf3239e0358e59de3f1202e4160a38df/gistfile1.txt).

Comment: Looking at your code I think the problem is that you are really just writing Ruby code in C. You can only gain performance if you do "real low-level programming". For example, to significantly gain performance, you would probably need to use a C array in contrast to a Ruby array. I am by no means an expert in Ruby C extensions, but I am pretty sure just calling Ruby's API methods from C won't give you any performance benefits, since it's essentially no different from directly writing Ruby code.

Comment: @Rafal Chmiel: Using C to automate/script individual Ruby API calls will not usually increase speed - in fact it may reduce effective speed. I cannot tell if that is your problem here, because your question does not cover what you are trying speed up, just your assumption on what you think the problem is. I doubt very much that `stack = rb_iv_get(self, "@stack");` takes 0.1 seconds per call, so this is some aggregate difference of the whole algorithm in a benchmark, yes?

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers, and now I know a little bit more about what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think your speed problem is directly to do with calls to `rb_iv_get`. You should first consider whether you need to keep the data in a Ruby object *at all*. It may be far more effective to have the data in a C data structure, and convert it to or from Ruby data as needed by methods your extension adds to the class.

However, if you need to manage a Ruby object as an integral part of a C extension, then you can keep the value as part of a C `struct` and implement an accessor for the Ruby side to see it if necessary. Then you don't need to call `rb_iv_get` at all to access the `VALUE` in C.

First you will need to understand how to use `Data_Wrap_Struct` and `Data_Get_Struct` macros from ruby.h - the [Extending Ruby chapter of Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html) is a good place to see this in action, with the CD Jukebox example.

Then, armed with this, you can make one of your structure components a VALUE:

```
typedef struct my_structure {
  int some_number;
  VALUE some_ruby_val;
} MyStructure;
```

In addition to the CD Jukebox example, you will need to implement a function that marks `some_ruby_val` as being in use (if you don't do this, Ruby's garbage collector will recycle the memory, and you could end up with some other object being pointed to - usually that will get you a segfault):

```
void my_structure_gc_mark( MyStructure *mine ) {
  rb_gc_mark( mine->some_ruby_val );
  return;
}
```

When you use `Data_Wrap_Struct`, you tell it about this function, as well as the destroy function documented in the link:

```
Data_Wrap_Struct( klass, my_structure_gc_mark, my_structure_destroy, mine );
```

Ruby then takes care of calling it when necessary.

Finally, to get your extension-held Ruby data, you just unwrap the structure and refer it like any other part of a `struct`. By way of example, here is how you would implement the accessor method for the above:

```
VALUE my_ext_get_some_ruby_val( VALUE self ) {
  MyStructure *mine;
  Data_Get_Struct( self, MyStructure, mine );
  return mine->some_ruby_val;
}
```

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks for your answer. I'll find out more.